# How do I find out which files were downloaded outside my continent (and by whom)?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have been monitoring Cloud Storage billing daily and saw two unexpected, large spikes in "Download Worldwide Destinations (excluding Asia & Australia)" this month. The cost for this SKU is typically around US$2-4 daily; however, these two daily spikes have been $89 and $15.

I have enabled GCS Bucket Logging soon after the $89 spike, hoping to deduce what causes it the next time it happens, but when the $15 spike happened yesterday, I was unable to pinpoint which service or files downloaded have caused this spike.

There is a Log field named `Location`, but it appears to be linked to the region where a bucket is located, not the location of the downloader (that would contribute to the "Worldwide Destinations" egress).

As far as I know, my services are all in the `southamerica-east1` region, but it's possible that there is either a legacy service or a misconfigured one that has been responsible for these spikes.

The bucket that did show up outside my region is in the U.S., but I concluded that it is not responsible for the spikes because the files there are under 30 kB and have only been downloaded 8 times according to the logs.

Is there any way to filter the logs so that it tells me as much information as possible to help me track down what is adding up the "Download Worldwide Destinations" cost? Specifically:

- which files were downloaded
- if it was one of my Google Cloud services, which one it was

Comment: Did you have activated the audit logs?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, under "Log Name" I see one option: `cloudaudit.googleapis.com/data_access`

Comment: 1) Cloud Audit Logs do not track access to public objects. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/audit-logging#restrictions 2) Enable **usage logs** and export the data to a new bucket. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#should-you-use The logs will have the IP address, you will need to use a geolocation service to map addresses.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for the info, I will look at Usage logs. If you would like to post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable **usage logs** and export the log data to a new bucket.

[Google Cloud Usage logs & storage logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs)

The logs will contain the IP address, you will need to use a geolocation service to map IP addresses to city/country.

**Note:**

Cloud Audit Logs do not track access to public objects.

[Google Cloud Audit Logs restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/audit-logging#restrictions)